# On conditional expectation from tensor products

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a $\mathrm{II}_{1}$ factor. Does there exist a conditional expectation from $M^{\otimes 2}$ to $M$ preserving the trace $\tau^{\otimes 2}$?

Comment: Do you see $M$ as one tensor component of $M \otimes M$? If an inclusion of factors preserves the traces it extends to the preduals. Dualizing you get an expectation. It seems that $M \otimes \mathbb{C} 1 \subset M \otimes M$ is trace-preseving.

Comment: there are many embeddings of $M$ to $M\otimes M$, are you talking about $x\rightarrow x\otimes I$?

Comment: Yes, but that is precisely what should be clarified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $N$ is **any** subalgebra of a II$_1$ factor, then there exists a trace preserving conditional expectation from the ambient II$_1$ factor onto $N$. The proof can be found in any standard text book on von Neumann algebras.

Comment: If anyone wants a more specific reference that's open to the public, there's [this article by Takesaki](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(72)90004-3). Specifically, apply the main theorem using the trace as the semifinite normal weight, and observe that the modular automorphism group is trivial for a trace, so the invariance condition is automatic. The proof can be done more simply in this case, and makes a nice exercise in understanding the general case.